# How to avoid variables like $HOME from being translated in a script

Tags: linux, rpm, specifications, home-directory

I have a shell script that builds an RPM Package. For the files(%files) section I have something like this

```
%attr(766, $USER, $myGroup) $HOME/Documents/...../.
```

However, the $HOME is translated when the script is run and I have `/home/userid/` in the SPEC file that is generated , instead of simply having $HOME.

I just want my SPEC FILE to have $HOME. How can I stop $HOME from being translated into its actual value.

Comment: enclose them in single quotes  ` ' `

Comment: Why do you want the `%files` section of the spec file to have `$HOME` in it? I don't believe that is going to be interpreted by rpm in any sane way (and certainly isn't going to be the home directory of the user installing the RPM).

Answer (score 2):

Escape the dollar ($) sign in variable in your script.... using back slash ('\') as below

```
%attr(766, $USER, $myGroup) \$HOME/Documents/..../.
```

Comment: I believe even $USER variable also needs to be changed to \$USER